# Easy, cheap way to record TV footage to a PC?

Tags: recording, video-capture

I have a spare PC that I'd like to set up for recording sessions from my TV and I have an HD video capture card, but I'm not sure how to go about setting this up.

Anyone know of a simple way or a good article on how to do this?

Comment: Sorry to edit it so crudely, but this ensures that people won't close it as "Not computer related" and still get you valid answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have a HD video capture card, you simply need to find the latest drivers for it. If you are using a Windows version that includes Media centre, and the drivers are compatible, you will be able to use that to do your recording.

If however the drivers are not compatible, you are going to have to look for software that is compatible - If you again take a look at the website, they should have software that you can download which will help you do the recording.

After this or if it doesn't help, you may want to take a look at distributions of Linux that are built especially for TV recording - but without knowing your card, I really can't guarantee any compatibility. I would start by looking at [Mythbuntu](http://www.mythbuntu.org/).